# Visual Studio C++ Multiple Project Solution Setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, architecture, project, solution

## 0. Disclaimer

This question is only about **Visual Studio C++ project/solution configuration** and may involve subjectivity.

However, the idea behind this post is to share our approaches to configure a large Visual Studio solution.

I'm not considering any tool like `CMake`/`Premake` here.

## 1. Problem

- How do you handle a large scaled C++ application architecture and configuration using Visual Studio?
- What is, for you, the best way to setup a new Visual Studio solution composed of multiple projects?
- What Visual Studio project/solution configuration feature are you trying to avoid? (*Ex: Filters instead of folders*)

## 2. Personnal approach

### 2.1. Context

I'm a software developer for a video game company, so I will take a very simplified game engine architecture to illustrate my words:

[image]

### 2.2. File Structure

My Visual Studio solution would probably look something like this:

[image]

Where `Application` is an *executable* and every other projects are *libraries* (Dynamically linked).

My approach would be to separate each project into two folders: `include`, `src`

[image]

And the inner structure would be separated into folders following my namespaces:

[image]

### 2.3. Project Configuration

*The following lines will assume there is only one `$(Configuration)` and `$(Platform)` available (Ex: `Release-x64`) and that referencing .lib files into `Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies` is done for each project.*

I would here define a `Bin` (Output), `Bin-Int` (Intermediate output) and `Build` (Organized output) folder, let's say they are located in `$(SolutionDir)`:

- `$(SolutionDir)Bin\`
- `$(SolutionDir)Bin-Int\`
- `$(SolutionDir)Build\`

The `Bin` and `Bin-Int` folders are playgrounds for the compiler, while the `Build` folder is populated by each project post-build event:

- `$(SolutionDir)Build\$(ProjectName)\include\` (Project includes)
- `$(SolutionDir)Build\$(ProjectName)\lib\` (.lib files)
- `$(SolutionDir)Build\$(ProjectName)\bin\` (.dll files)

This way, each `$(SolutionDir)Build\$(ProjectName)\` can be shared as an independent library.

*Note: Following explainations may skip `$(SolutionDir)` from the `Build` folder path to simplify reading.*

If `B` is dependent of `A`, `Build\B\include\` will contain `B` and `A` includes. The same way, `Build\B\bin\` will contain `B` and `A` binaries and `Build\B\lib\` will contain `B` and `A` .lib files (If and only if `B` is ok to expose `A` to its user, otherwise, only `B` .lib files will be added to `Build\B\lib\`).

Projects reference themselves relatively to `Build\` folders. Thus, if `B` is dependent of `A`, `B` include path will reference `$(SolutionDir)Build\A\include\` (And not `$(SolutionDir)A\include\`), so any include used by `A` will be available for `B` without specifying it explicitly. (But result to sections `2.6.2.`, `2.6.3.` and `2.6.4.` technical limitations).

After that, I make sure that my solution has a proper `Project Dependencies` configuration so the `Build Order`, when building the whole solution, will consider and respect my project dependencies.

### 2.4. User Project Configuration

Our `EngineSDK` user (Working onto `Application`) will only have to setup `Application` such as:

- **Include Directories**: `$(SolutionDir)Build\Engine\include\`
- **Library Directory**: `$(SolutionDir)Build\Engine\lib\`
- **Post-build**: Copy `$(SolutionDir)Build\Engine\bin\*` to `$(OutDir)`
- **Additional Dependencies**: Any .lib file upstream in the dependency hierarchy is listed here

This is the typical  Visual Studio configuration flow of a lot of C++ library.

*Common library folder architecture that I try to preserve:*

```
lib\
include\
bin\
```

Here are some example of libraries using this folder architecture model (Do note that `bin` is exclusively for dynamically linked libraries as statically linked libraries don't bother with DLLs):

- SFML: https://www.sfml-dev.org/
- SDL: https://www.libsdl.org/

### 2.5. Advantages

- Clear folder architecture
- Ability to export a library directly by copy-pasting or zipping a sub-folder of `$(SolutionDir)Build\`

### 2.6. Technical limitations

The approach I wrote here has some drawbacks. These limitations are the reason of this post as I want to improve myself:

#### 2.6.1. Tedious configuration

Dealing with 10 or less projects is fine, however, with bigger solutions (15+ projects), it can quickly become a mess. Project configurations are very rigid, and a small change in project architecture can result into hours of project configuration and debugging.

#### 2.6.2. Post-build limitation

Let's consider a simple dependency case:

- `C` is dependent of `B` and `B` is dependent of `A`.
- `C` is an executable, and `B` and `A` are libraries
- `B` and `A` post-build events update their `Build\$(ProjectName)\` directory

When changing the source code of `A`, then compiling it, `Build\A\` will get updated. However, as `B` has been previously compiled (Before `A` changes), its `Build\B\` folder contains a copy of previous `A` binaries and includes. Thus, executing `C` (Which is only aware of `B` as a dependency), will use old `A` binaries/includes. A workaround I found for this problem is to manually trigger `B` post-build event before executing `C`. However, forgetting to trigger an intermediate project post-build can result into headaches during debugging (Not loaded symbols, wrong behaviour...).

### 2.6.3. Multiple times single header reference

Another limitation for this approach is "Multiple times single header reference".

This problem can be explained by considering the project dependency image at section **2.1.**.
Considering that `Graphics` and `Physics` are both including `Maths` headers, and that `Engine` is including `Build\Graphics\include\` and `Build\Physics\include\`, typing a header name will show multiple identical results:

[image]

### 2.6.4. De-synchronized symbol referencing

If `B` is dependent of `A` and any header changes in `A` (for instance, we add a new function), `Rescan File`/`Rescan Solution` will be needed to access the new symbol from `B`.

Also, navigating to files or symbol can make us move to the wrong header (Copied header instead of the original one).

## 3. Interrogations and learning perspectives

### 3.1. Project Reference

During my Visual Studio software developer journey, I came through the project `Reference` concept, but I can't find how it can solve the technical limitations of my current approach, nor how it can helps me to re-think it.

### 3.2. Property sheets

As every project configuration of my solution is following the same principle but the content (Include dirs, library dirs...) for each one is different, I'm not sure how to make a great usage of property sheets.

### 3.3. Exploring GitHub

Currently I'm struggling finding some good project architecture references. I would be pleased finding some Visual Studio configured solution on GitHub or any code sharing platform. (I know that `CMake` and `Premake` are prefered in most case when sharing code, however, learning more about Visual Studio project configuration is my actual goal).

Thanks for reading my words, I hope that you are also interested into discussing about this subject and maybe we can share our approaches.

Comment: Is there an actual question that can be answered here? Your presentation is good, and as a AAA game developer for many years I understand how much "fun" it is to maintain a large project, but I'm not sure this is on-topic here as presented.

Comment: Just my two cents: I tuned my VS2008 projects carefully in a text editor even though it ended up into roundabout 50 projects in the resp. solution. (With copy/paste, I considered it maintainable.) With a little helper tool, we even could convert that into make files (for Linux/g++). However, switching to VS2010 was impossible. The migration just failed to understand my project files although they worked very satisfying in VS2008. I considered to write a migration tool myself - easy, VS2008 projects are XML based. Before I was able to invest into this we switched to CMake. End of story. ;-)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Use props files to hold common project settings otherwise cmake, gyp or some other project generator will allow you to define common functionality in a single place and include in multiple projects

Comment: @RetiredNinja You are right, there isn’t a simple question in my post. The idea is more to expose and share our knowledge about a such important aspect of software development. It can seem off-topic compared to most questions asked on StackOverflow. Otherwise, I’m pretty sure It can find its public here. Maybe a blog post or a forum thread would have been more adapted, but I’m not sure the public would have been there. It has been years since I’m trying to improve my approach (From Google to StackOverflow) and I would have loved finding this kind of post to learn new stuff.